# ng-show attribut causes html block blinking (beginner)

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, ng-show

On my login page, when I enter wrong credentials (login/pass), an error message is displayed in red.

In login.html :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="authenticationError"
                translate="login.messages.error.authentication">
                <strong></strong>
            </div>
```

If I set `ng-show="true"` explicitely, The message is persistent on the screen ; (fortunately).
The problem comes when `ng-show` is dynamic (with `authenticationError` variable)

When this variable is set to true, then the error message appears but left 1 second on the screen and then disappear.

Behind the scene (controller + service) :

**login.controller.js :**

```
$scope.login = function () {

           // event.preventDefault();
            Auth.login({
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password,
                rememberMe: $scope.rememberMe
            }).then(function () {
                $scope.authenticationError = false;
              //  if()
                if ($rootScope.previousStateName === 'register') {
                    $state.go('home');
                } else {
                    $rootScope.back();
                }
            }).catch(function () {
                $scope.authenticationError = true;
            });
        };
```

**auth.service.js :**

```
angular.module('tessicommunicationApp')
    .factory('Auth', function Auth($rootScope, $state, $q, $translate, Principal, AuthServerProvider, Account, Register, Activate, Password, PasswordResetInit, PasswordResetFinish) {
        return {
            login: function (credentials, callback) {
                var cb = callback || angular.noop;
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                console.log("login ...");
                AuthServerProvider.login(credentials).then(function (data) {
                    // retrieve the logged account information
                    Principal.identity(true).then(function(account) {
                        // After the login the language will be changed to
                        // the language selected by the user during his registration
                        $translate.use(account.langKey).then(function(){
                            $translate.refresh();
                        });
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    });
                    return cb();
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    this.logout();
                    deferred.reject(err);
                    console.log("erreur login !");
                    return cb(err);
                }.bind(this));

                return deferred.promise;
            },
```

**auth.session.service.js :**

```
angular
        .module('tessicommunicationApp')
        .factory(
                'AuthServerProvider',
                function loginService($http, localStorageService, $window, $state, $cookies) {
                    return {
                        login : function(credentials) {
                            var data = 'j_username='
                                    + encodeURIComponent(credentials.username)
                                    + '&j_password='
                                    + encodeURIComponent(credentials.password)
                                    + '&remember-me=' + credentials.rememberMe
                                    + '&submit=Login';
                            return $http
                                    .post(
                                            'api/authentication',
                                            data,
                                            {
                                                headers : {
                                                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                                }
                                            }).success(function(response) {
                                        return response;
                                    });
                        },
```

Tell me if you need more code.

***The context is :***

1) I need to debug this ticket.

2) I didn't code anything of this web application (especially front-end part)

3) I almost have NO knowledges in AngularJS (just theory a little).

I wish you will help me to solve my first ticket :).*

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing a parenthesis and extra parenthesis at the end of the statement here:

```
 }).catch(function (err) {
                    this.logout();
                    deferred.reject(err);
                    console.log("erreur login !");
                    return cb(err);
                }.bind(this));// <-- missing parenthesis
```

It should be like:

```
 }).catch(function (err) {
                        this.logout();
                        deferred.reject(err);
                        console.log("erreur login !");
                        return cb(err);
                    }).bind(this);
```

Something else you can try when suspect about changes occurring without you know is monitoring the variable change with a `$watch` like:

```
$scope.countChange = 0;

$scope.$watch('authenticationError', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.countChange = $scope.countChange + 1;
  console.log('Change count :',$scope.countChange , ' New Value =', newValue );
});
```

Comment: You are wrong for the parenthesis. It is OK in the question. When watching variable change, all is OK (true once when invalid login/pass or false when valid). I suspect a problem of refresh/ajax, not the code directly but a side effect somewhere.

Comment: So you are saying that  `}.bind` exists; really.... So this works `function (){ }.bind()` in the same way this works `(function (){ }).bind()`

Comment: Yes. If I do like you say, I have a syntax error in the browser console. What I see, is that when the error message display a very short time, the page continue loading (I see progress bar) and then I suppose it re-refresh the content. The error message wipe out.